# ::class en php para que sirve

Tags: php, objeto, class

Hola a todos les pido ayuda ya que mientras llamada a un método de una clase que tengo en php mi editor de código me lo autocompletó de esta forma:

```
MiClase::class
```

Mi pregunta es ¿para qué sirve el `::class`? He visto que también en algunas librerías de php lo usan para referirse a un objeto pero ¿cuál es su función? Desde ya gracias

Comment: Es una [constante de clase especial](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.constants.php#example-231).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que hace ::class es devolver el namespace que usa la clase.
Es decir si tu tienes una clase **MiClase** que usa un namespace diferente al que estás usando en tu código principal, al añadirle el ::class de la siguiente manera **MiClase::class** al usar esa clase sabrá que tiene que usar el namespace propio de la clase **MiClase** y no usará el namespace del código principal.